# Using Socket.io with typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I am working on establishing a websocket connection between a Node app and a React app. However I cannot seem to get function this.io.on() to run in my listen method in class socket. The server logs "listen" but not 'Connected client on port %s.', this.port. My question is why it doesn't?

File index.ts in server application.

```
/// <reference types="@types/node" />

// Imports.
import * as http from 'http';
import App from './App';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';
import { SocketIO, Server } from 'socket.io';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = http.createServer(App);

// Start the server.
App.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
  return console.error(err);
}
  new socket(server);

  return console.log(`Server is listening on ${port}`);
});


class socket {

  private server: Server;
  private io: SocketIO.Server;
  private port = 3000;

  constructor(server) {
      this.createServer(server);
      this.sockets();
      this.listen();
  }

  private createServer(server: any): void {
      this.server = server;
  }

  private sockets(): void {
      this.io = socketIo(this.server);
  }

  private listen(): void {
      console.log("listen");
      this.io.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
          console.log('Connected client on port %s.', this.port);
          socket.on('message', (m: any) => {
              console.log('[server](message): %s', JSON.stringify(m));
              this.io.emit('message', m);
          });

          socket.on('disconnect', () => {
              console.log('Client disconnected');
          });
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong `this` resulting in `this.io` to be `undefined`.

## Fix

Use an [arrow function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html):

```
  private listen = (): void => { // ARROW
      console.log("listen");
      this.io.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
```

Comment: we don''t want "any" I guess. The power of typing is if we specify the right type we can access all object methods right through ide without running the code and debugging